# I do not have question, But system banned me

Tags: support

I do not have any questions in my list, But system sends me 'question ban' message.
How can I get rid of it? Why does it ban me?

My questions are not listed in [my questions tab](https://serverfault.com/users/158280/mohammad-etemaddar?tab=questions).

Comment: As ChrisS stated, the questions were deleted but count against you. Deleted questions do *not* show on your questions tab; they only show to moderators of the site.

Comment: All of your previous questions have been poorly received, most likely because you failed to read any of the information pertaining to he scope of this site. It's probably a good thing that a the system won't let you ask a new question bit just in case it does please read [about] carefully.

Comment: The reason for your not seeing the deleted questions could be here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile

Comment: @Iain: The issue is not up to users, But it's about moderators; The system does not show the deleted questions to the user; And needs clearance. I did not see my questions about one month ago. I though there is a problem with system.

Comment: Please read the link I provided, there is useful information in it that will help you and here it is again http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile

Answer (score 8):

You have 3 questions:

https://serverfault.com/questions/579312/
https://serverfault.com/questions/477182/
https://serverfault.com/questions/477178/

Deleted question still count against you.

---

**How to fix the ban:**
[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: Thank you, But from where can I find them? they are not [here](http://serverfault.com/users/158280/mohammad-etemaddar?tab=questions).

Comment: Do the links provided not work?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I prefer to ask my question from others.

Comment: You might "*prefer to ask my question from others*", but what Chris told you is correct @MohammadEtemaddar - the facts won't change because I'm telling you them instead of Chris, or a third person is instead of Chris or myself. Is there any part of Chris' answer that you do not understand?

Comment: @RobM , Anyway, the comment was not my answer :). I prefer to get my correct answer.

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar You already got the correct answer.

Comment: @MichaelHampton : Ok, Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I think something is getting lost in translation here. This comment conversation doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you can't see your deleted questions is that they were deleted more than 60 days ago. This mSE Q&A refers. [What is the 'deleted recent questions' page in the user profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile)

The system is aware of these poorly received questions and will not let you ask new ones. There seems little you can do at this time to fix that. This is probably a Good Thing<sup>TM</sup>.

Comment: I do not like this system and it's high rank users.

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar Log out, don't come back *simples*